# Increment in shell script

Tags: shell

I am counting my list by below command

```
my_list=`echo $pdca`

tr -dc '|' <<<"$my_list" | wc -w
```

which counts the words from the list like : `abc|hty|jid|hjik|kilhj`

```
word belong to a : abc
0
word belong to b : hty|jid
1
word belong to c : hjik|kilhj
1
```

Can you please help me here to increment the count by 1. Means where its counting 0 it should count 1 and where its counting 1 should count 2

please assist me here.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: Assign the count to a variable, then use `$((var++))` to increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not even remotely understand the question, but if

```
tr -dc '|' <<<"$my_list" | wc -w
```

is giving you one less than you want, try padding the data:

```
{ echo dummy; tr -dc '|' <<<"$my_list"; } | wc -w
```

That may be cleaner/easier than incrementing a variable, depending on the rest of the script.  (It would help if you included a complete script that demonstrates the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

To count fields separated by some delimiter you better use `awk`, some examples:

```
awk -F '|' '{print NF}' <<< "abc|hty|jid|hjik|kilhj"
5

awk -F '|' '{print NF}' <<< "abc"
1

awk -F '|' '{print NF}' <<< "hty|jid"
2
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F '|'     # set custom field separator as |
{print NF} # print number of fields in input record
```